# How to add a Cocoa pod dependency in the shared functionality of a multiplatform Kotlin project? (not for iOS app itself)

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

How to add a Cocoa pod dependency in the shared functionality of a multiplatform Kotlin project? So that we could implement "expect-actual" with "actual" for iOS using classes from the Cocoa pod. Read all possible materials on this but can't make this working.

Comment: Post your build config. What do you mean by "shared"?

Comment: Just creating a vanilla 'New Project' in Android studio, with MMP plugin, choosing the project profile 'Kotlin Multiplatform App'.